# Do I need a hardware interface for Roboteq Brushless DC Motor Controllers to control differential drive AMR?

Tags: controller, ros

I want to control differential drive Autonomous Mobile Robot with 2 Brushless DC Motors. Its a 2 wheels differential drive AMR. I have Roboteq FAMILY controller and was able to use the ROS2 driver , so can run the motors. I was using this github to make the ROS2 driver works ([ROS2 Roboteq driver](https://github.com/DoanNguyenTrong/roboteq_controller_ros/tree/galactic-devel).

So Im using CPU based AMR and the whole SDK is in the CPU. So my question is do I need to use ROS2 control package to control my robot and use the provided hardware interfaces . They provide some demos and most suitable for this case is example2 ([hardware interface for differential drive robot](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/tree/master/example_2)

When launch the Roboteq driver i have the following topic lists

```
/cmd_vel
/encoder_count
/encoder_speed
/feedback
/hall_count
/hall_speed
/motor_amps
/motor_command
/parameter_events
/read
/rosout
/volts
```

The config file is

```
roboteq_controller_node:
  ros__parameters:
    serial_port: "/dev/ttyACM0" # Udev rule to make a virtual port that's associated to specific hw
    baudrate: 115200
    cmd_vel_topic: "/cmd_vel"

    closed_loop: true

    # For differential drive control (dual channel controller)
    diff_drive_mode: true
    wheel_circumference: 0.6594 # [m]
    track_width: .6223 # [m]
    max_rpm: 100.0 # [rpm]
    encoder_resolution: 1024

    # For querying data from the motor controller
    frequency: 50   #higher frequency (value is in ms)
    query:
      motor_amps : ?A 
      motor_command : ?M
      hall_count : ?Cb
      hall_speed : ?BS
      volts : ?V
      feedback : ?F 
      # battery_amps : ?BA
      # power : ?P          
      # fault_flag : ?FF  
      # motor_amps2 : ?MA
      # motor_command2 : ?FM
      # hall_count2 : ?FM
      # hall_speed2 : ?FS
      # volts2 : ?V
      # feedback2 : ?rmp 
      # battery_amps2 : ?PHA
      # power2 : ?sns          
      # fault_flag2 : ?S  
      # status_flag : ?FS
      # firmware_id : ?FID  
      encoder_count : ?C
      encoder_speed : ?S
```

So my question is do I still need the ros2_control package and the hardware interface or can just have a node to use the Roboteq ROS2 driver to control the AMR?

Thanks